# --- in is already defined in main(java.lang.String[]) --- ERROR MESSAGE DRIVING ME MAD

Tags: java

I'm a student starting out on my first programming module. The textbook I'm working from is 'Java for Everyone', Cay Horstmann. I'm on chapter 2.4 - Constants. I have copied and checked (over 15 times!) the code directly from the book, however every time I compile it produces the compile error **in is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])**.

It highlights **Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);** as being the problem. I have written another extremely simple program which also includes **Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);** and I had exactly the same problem.

I have tried to find the solution, I've reinstalled both Java JDK and BlueJ (compiler), but nothing has worked. I have Googled the problem, but I'm unable to find anything which matches my problem. I am a Java virgin, so to be honest it's pretty difficult to work out where I should be looking.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm behind a couple of weeks already, and this is holding my progress up considerably.

Thanks, in advance, for any advice offered.

All the best,

Vicky

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Volume2 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        final double BOTTLE_VOLUME = 2;  
        final double LITRES_PER_OUNCE = 0.0296; 
        final double CAN_VOLUME = 12 * LITRES_PER_OUNCE; 

        System.out.print("Please enter quantity of bottles: ");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int bottles = in.nextInt();

        double totalVolume = totalVolume * BOTTLE_VOLUME;

        System.out.print("Please enter the number of cans: ");

        **Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);** // This is highlighted as being the problem

        int cans = in.nextInt();

        double additionalVolume = cans * CAN_VOLUME;

        totalVolume = totalVolume + additionalVolume;

        System.out.print("The total volume is: ");
        System.out.println(totalVolume);

    }
}
```

---

Error Message: **in is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])**

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);   // FIRST ONE HERE

int bottles = in.nextInt();
double totalVolume = totalVolume * BOTTLE_VOLUME;
System.out.print("Please enter the number of cans: ");

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);   // SECOND ONE HERE
```

Have a look at that code segment. You are *indeed* trying to create two copies of `in`, exactly as the error message suggests.

In a normal situation where you wanted to reuse a variable, you would simply *assign* to it the second time, such as with:

```
int xyzzy = 42;             // Create it here.
doSomethingWith (xyzzy);
xyzzy = 314159;             // NOTE: no "int" here, simple reuse.
doSomethingWith (xyzzy);
```

But, in your case, this does not apply, you've simply declared the variable twice.

So, subscribing to the "create variables as late as you possibly can" philosophy, I would get rid of the first one, it's not needed. You *could* get rid of the second but that afore-mentioned philosophy has served me well, ensuring that creation and use of objects are localised.

Comment: Thank you all for your speedy replies. I can't understand what on earth I was doing. I've removed the second scanner, and edited the totalVolume, and it works. I can only think the many hours of studying had altered my brain function! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

So the error message is exactly correct - you already have something named `in` a few lines before the line with the error. In your specific case, just remove the second declaration, since it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear: you've already declared a variable named `in` inside `main()`. In fact, the declaration is identical, which means the second one is unnecessary. Delete the offending line, and the later code will still be able to benefit from the first declaration; everything will work fine.

You only need one `Scanner` to read from `System.in` -- once you've created one you don't need to create another; just keep reusing the one you've already made.